# JQuery Select Populate

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, autofill

i have to items on my html

a Input text (company)  field and a select (Company_List)

when user types in the text field i want jQuery to use /Home/SearchSynonym/ to get the names and display it in select (the SearchSynonym takes the value user types and do a wildcard search and returns   ID and NAME )

can some one help , am new ti jQuery

Leb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clarify as to in which format does SearchSynonym return the IDs and NAMEs? Is it in JSON? If it is in JSON, then try the following:

```
var companyList = $("#Company_List");

$("#company").change( function(){
    $.getJSON("/Home/SearchSynonym/",{ query: $(this).val() }, function(response){
        var responseList = "";
        $.each(result, function(index, item){
            responseList += "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.name + "</option>";
        });
        companyList.html(responseList);
    });
});
```

This would work if your 'company' text field bears the id="company" in the tag decleration,  your 'Company_List' dropdown bears the id="Company_List" in the tag decleration and your server end receives the parameter "query" for pulling records.

Comment: yes the SearchSynonym returns JSON,  so if i add the code when user starts typing in the company text input  the Select will be populated with the returns from the SearchSynonym  query?

Comment: how can i delay the search? for example if use types fast i want to delay by about 2 seconds?

Comment: You can use setTimeout. Try this code: 

var companyList = $("#Company_List");

$("#company").change( function(){
    setTimeout( function() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/SearchSynonym/",{ query: $(this).val() }, function(response){
            var responseList = "";
            $.each(result, function(index, item){
                responseList += "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.name + "</option>";
            });
            companyList.html(responseList);
        });
    }, 2000);
});

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout. Try this:

```
var companyList = $("#Company_List");

$("#company").change( function(){
    setTimeout( function() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/SearchSynonym/",{ query: $(this).val() }, function(response){
            var responseList = "";
            $.each(result, function(index, item){
                responseList += "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.name + "</option>";
            });
            companyList.html(responseList);
        });
    }, 2000);    
});
```

The value of 2000 indicates a 2 second delay.

Comment: setTimeout dosn't seems to want to submit the query , i changed $("#company").change to $("#company").keyup. without timeout it works

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined jquery-2.0.0.js:3907
jQuery.fn.extend.val jquery-2.0.0.js:3907
(anonymous function)

Comment: $.getJSON("/Home/SearchSynonym/",{ query: $("#company").val() }, function(response) and it worked